# Errors with ionic4 admob Plugin

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic4

**Home page ts code**

```
    import { PostsService } from "./../posts.service";
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from "@angular/router";
    import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
    import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

    @Component({
      selector: "app-home",
      templateUrl: "home.page.html",
      styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"]
    })
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
      constructor(
        private postSrvc: PostsService,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private admobFree: AdMobFree
      ) {
        this.showBannerAd();
      }

      posts$: Observable<any>;
      loadPost(post: any) {
        this.router.navigate(["/posts", post.id]);
      }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.posts$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap(
            (params: ParamMap) =>
              params.get("category")
                ? this.postSrvc.fetchPostsByCategory(params.get("category"))
                : this.postSrvc.fetchPosts()
          )
        );
      }


      async showBannerAd() {
        try {
          const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
            id: 'unit id',
            isTesting: true,
            autoShow: true
          }

          this.adMobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

          const result = await this.adMobFree.banner.prepare();
          console.log(result);
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }

    }
```

**app module ts code**

```
    import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";
    import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
    import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";
    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
    import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

    import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        AdMobFree,
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**all ERRORs**

> [ng]   ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(13,11): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent)[]; entryComponents: undefined[]; imports: (ModuleWithProvid...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
>
> [ng]   Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
>
> [ng]     Type '(typeof SplashScreen | AdMobFreeOriginal | { provide: typeof RouteReuseStrategy; useClass: typeof...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
>
> [ng]       Type 'typeof SplashScreen | AdMobFreeOriginal | { provide: typeof RouteReuseStrategy; useClass: typeof ...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>
> [ng]         Type 'AdMobFreeOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>
> [ng]           Type 'AdMobFreeOriginal' is not assignable to type 'ClassProvider'.
>
> [ng]             Property 'provide' is missing in type 'AdMobFreeOriginal'.
>
> [ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts(19,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AdMobFree'.
>
> [ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts(48,12): error TS2551: Property 'adMobFree' does not exist on type 'HomePage'. Did you mean 'admobFree'?
>
> [ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts(50,33): error TS2551: Property 'adMobFree' does not exist on type 'HomePage'. Did you mean 'admobFree'?

Answer (score 4):

**TRY by changing this** :

```
import { AdMobFree} from '@ionic-native/admob-free';
```

to this :

```
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free/ngx';
```